rn-card-scanner card not scanning or triggering any event
I am trying to integrate rn-credit-card in react native app but the scanning not working camera trying to scan but not triggering any error or response I have cloned an example app as well and run but it's also not returning data after scanning it's not going to the card details screen always remaining on scan screen when a card is placed in a frame.
I am using Redmi note 8 Android version is 11
